# related field on odoo?

Tags: field, odoo

how to add a field related on odoo 
I would like to add a text field on stock.move related to stock.picking origin field 
I tried this :

```
_columns={       
    'sourcebl': fields.related('picking_id', 'origin',  type='char', relation='stock.picking', string='Class Description', store=True, readonly=True),
          }
```

do you have any Idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the old api it work fine now :

```
_columns={
'sourcebon': fields.related('picking_id', 'origin', string="Origin", type="char",store=True, readonly=True),
}
```

Comment: Ok, great ! But if you use Odoo, you must use the new API for a better compatibility and better performance.

Answer (score 15):

You can find more information here : [Link](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#related-field)

In the new API, there is not anymore fields.related. You should define your related field like this :

```
   sourcebl = fields.Char(string='Class Description', related='picking_id.origin')
```

Comment: This piece of Python code is to put where to achieve that ?

Comment: Its New API field declaration, so it will be with other fields.

Comment: Extremely helpful. It's included in the docs, but hard to notice.