# Related fields odoo10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

hello how can I do related in fields :

```
class etude(models.Model):
_name= 'etude.risque'

incendie = fields.Integer('Suppresseur Anti_Incendie', related='anti_incendie')
```

second class

```
class risque(models.Model):
_name='risques.risque'
_rec_name='nom_risque'
anti_incendie = fields.Many2one('risques.incendie', string="Suppresseur Anti_Incendie",required=True)
```

how can I do  incendie in class etude related to anti_incendie in class risque

Comment: Possible duplicate of [related field on odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452805/related-field-on-odoo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to declare a many2one field with risque class:

```
risque_id = fields.Many2one('risques.risque', 'Risque')
```

and then you need to create your related class using the relation created. If the field you want to relate is a many2one you need to create a many2one related field:

```
incendie = fields.Many2one(related='risque_id.anti_incendie')
```

I hope this help you.